# How to read/write to a HID device?

Tags: c, linux, hid, msp430

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <linux/hiddev.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
```

My HID device shows up as `dev/usb/hiddev0`.

I can successfully open() the device with

```
fd = open("/dev/usb/hiddev0", O_RDWR);
```

And generate correct device reports by printing the values in my `HIDIOCGDEVINFO` struct.

Now I need to send 64 byte packets to the device. (msp430F5510 BSL). Can I write to the device using ioctl or write()? Are there any examples around?

Comment: Perhaps this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846341/write-something-to-linux-hid-device

Comment: Here's another potentially helpful post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17679480/details-on-usb-no-luck-so-far/17679571#17679571